# Functions works on command line, but not in script

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pygraphviz

I have the following function defined in its own file called MTG.py.  It is supposed to take an adjacency matrix as an input, and create a graph.

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
import numpy as np

def matrix_to_graph(M):
    A = pgv.AGraph()
    for i in range(0, np.shape(M)[0]):
        for j in range(0, np.shape(M)[0]):
            if i < j and M[i][j] == 1:
                A.add_edge(i,j)
    A.write('M.dot')
    C = pgv.AGraph('M.dot')
    C.layout()
    C.draw('M.png')
```

When I run from the command line

```
from MTG import matrix_to_graph
M = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
matrix_to_graph(M)
```

I get exactly what I want, which is the correct graph printed to M.png.

However, if I add to the code above (with no indent, i.e. outside the definition of the function)

```
M = input("Enter an adjacency matrix:")
matrix_to_graph(M)
```

I get the error

```
 for i in range(0, np.shape(M)[0]):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I imagine this is happening because the input function is taking in what I *think* is a matrix, but is *actually* something else.  I've tried to rectify this by using np.matrix(M), but that turns my matrix in a 1x16 vector. I am new to Python, and I'm sure there are 1000 ways to do this better, but I really want to figure out why this particular way is not working.

I am using PyCharm 2017.1.3 (community edition, if that matters), and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3's `input` returns a `str`, it doesn't parse it to make a Python data structure just because the contents look like a Python literal. In this case, if you want to be able to enter a `list` of `list` of `int`s literal, I'd recommend [using `ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to (safely) convert from the string representing the matrix literal to the `list` itself:

```
import ast

M = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter an adjacency matrix:"))
```

You're probably used to Python 2, where `input` was equivalent to doing `eval(input(...))` in Python 3, but that version of `input` was dangerous and removed for good reason; `ast.literal_eval` gets you what you need without allowing arbitrary code execution.

Comment: I'm happy that I knew where the problem was coming from, and even happier that the fix was real easy.  Thanks.